# Parsing Certain Value in Textfile using PHP

Tags: php, parsing, text

I have this raw text file in PHP and I want to get a specific number. Here is the text file:

```
Bones - Price Guide and Exchange - 2007 Old School RuneScape Jump 
to content Search Advanced Search section: ForumsMembersHelp Files 
Calendar   View New Content      Sign In    Create Account Zybez 
Runescape Help Forums Members OSRS Price Guide 2007 RS Help Premium 
More Runescape Community → OSRS Price Guide → Bones Price Guide: Bones 
The charts and price calculations are currently undergoing a transition. 
Prices may be inaccurate until this is completed, especially for 
less-active items. Please be patient, and notify us of any major problems. 
Recent Trade Price: ~55 GP (rising) Average Sell Offer 50 GP Average Buy 
Offer 60 GP High Alchemy Value 1 GP View more Bones info on 2007rshelp.com 
All Time 90 Days 30 Days 7 Days Latest Offers Offer RS Name Time Info 
Selling 2,000 for 70 GP ea maulsurba11s 5 hours ago pm Buying 25 for 200
 GP ea placation 15 hours ago pm me soon Selling 500 for 60 GP ea iharleyquinn
 18 hours ago Buying 30 for 60 GP ea purple-mlk 18 hours ago Buying 500 for 
60 GP ea og-real-og 24 hours ago Buying 25 for 200 GP ea haxore 32 hours ago
 Buying 25 for 75 GP ea attack-hd 41 hours ago pm me pls ;) Buying 1,000 for
 75 GP ea pupz45 43 hours ago Buying 100 for 200 GP ea i3-a-l-l-e-n 44 hours
 ago Look up a price Post your offer I am BuyingSelling for GP ea. My RS Name
 is Contact me by PMCC Scam Alert Never meet a player in Brimhaven or Entrana. 
Anyone who asks is trying to steal your items. Helpful Links 2007 RuneScape 
Help & Info Bank and Inventory Sales Money Making Tips Join a RuneScape Clan
 Most-Traded Items Nature rune 212 Blue h'ween mask 935,095 Red h'ween mask 
1,135,278 Bow string 88 Yew logs 485 Abyssal whip 1,761,182 Green h'ween mask
 695,655 Yew longbow 740 Prayer potion (3) 6,630 Halloween mask set 2,855,149
 Get Help | API | All Items Created by the almighty No1 1000. Runescape 
Community → OSRS Price Guide → Bones Privacy Policy Change Theme     
IP.Board Graphite (3.3) Thoreau Dark (3.3) Thoreau (3.3) Mark Community 
Read Forums Members Mark all as read Help Community Forum Software by 
IP.Board Licensed to: Zybez Corporation Curse Curse is the #1 Resource 
for core online gamers. Not a Member? Get your Free Account! Sign up for 
Free! Featured SitesMore Guild Wars 2 Guru Guild Wars 2 Guru The latest 
and greatest on Tyria. LoL Pro LoL Pro Dominate with Pro LoL guides. 
MMO-Champion MMO-Champion Keep ahead with the champions of WoW coverage. 
GW2DB GW2DB Explore Tyria with Curse and GW2DB. Browse Core Curse MMO-Champion
 WowStead CurseForge WowAce SkyrimForge SC2Mapster Bukkit Forums LoLPro ExilePro
 Community Minecraft Forum Terraria Online Arena Junkies Guild Wars 2 Guru 
DiabloFans FPS General DarthHater Defiance Forum Wildstar Forums Database
 Guild Wars 2 DB Zybez DarthHater DB Aion Armory WoW Database Marriland Wiki
 Minecraft Wiki Terraria Wiki Wowpedia Skyrim Wiki Wiki SWTOR Dragon Nest Wiki
 Vindictus Wiki Back to Top About Us Advertising Privacy Policy Terms of Service
 Premium Terms of Service Curse Newsletter Jobs at Curse Handcrafted in San Francisco
 & Huntsville Font: Arial | Calibri | Lucida Console | Verdana  
 Font Size: 9px | 10px | 11px | 12px | 10pt | 12pt   Color:
```

I want to get the number after "Recent Trade Price:~" and the number will change anywhere from 1-7 digits so it needs to be work with all numbers. I am not sure how to parse the String correctly so I get just the number after "Recent Trade Price"

I have tried using:

```
$text = $html->plaintext;
$words = explode("Recent Trade Price:", $text);
echo $words[1];
```

But this gave me everything after so I think I'm halfway there. Could someone please help!

Comment: You're better off using Regular Expressions in this situation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: if `Average Sell Offer` always follows it you can explode $words using it, and use the first part

Comment: Could just explode on the average afterwards and take 0 index.

Comment: @wazy ditto would suffice!

Answer (score 3):

Try a Regular Expression:

```
preg_match("/Recent Trade Price:[^0-9]*([0-9]+)/",$yourtext,$matches);
$price=$matches[1];
```

The Regular Expression first searches after something that begins with "Recent Trade Price:". Then it will search all characters that are no numbers. Then it will match all the following numbers. These are enclosed in () because they need to go into the $matches array. $matches[0] is the whole string that the RegExp has matched, and [1] and so on are the parts that are in brackets. So this will never fail, as long as you have a Recent Trade Price in the input, even if the ~ is missing or any other character is before or after the number.

Comment: did you forgot to pass the `subject` parameter?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how rigid and structured this text will be.  Will there always be a space and '~' before the number?

Regular expressions will probably be the most useful here.  `preg_match` will help you with this.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
preg_match('/Recent Trade Price: ~(\d+)/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Would print:

```
Array ( [0] => Recent Trade Price: ~55 [1] => 55 )
```

**Edit**

Per your comment, if the number you're trying to get has commas in it, you can use a different regular expression that will grab all characters until the first space

```
preg_match('/Recent Trade Price: ~(\S+)/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Would print:

```
Array ( [0] => Recent Trade Price: ~555,000 [1] => 555,000 )
```

From there you can strip out the comma(s) as needed.  Again, this would depend on how rigid and predictable the text format is...

Comment: This works great except for bigger numbers with commas it will only get the numbers up to the commas. Is there someway I could get rid of the commas?

Answer (score 0):

You could do another explode after that and get the first word, like this:

```
$words = explode("Recent Trade Price:", $text);
$price = explode(" ",$words[1]);
echo $price[0];
```

Comment: use `explode(" ", $words[1])` instead of `explode(" ",$words)`